# how to perform sorting operation for a grid view using linq,?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, linq

How to perform sorting operation for a grid view .I have done this(below code) but it is
throwing following error.

Error:

```
 the type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>,
     System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<TKey>)' 
    cannot be inferred from the usage.
```

code:

```
gridview1.DataSource = (from bk in bookList
                                join ordr in bookOrders
                                on bk.BookID equals ordr.BookID
                                select new
                                {
                                    BookID = bk.BookID,
                                    BookNm = bk.BookNm,
                                    PaymentMode = ordr.PaymentMode
                                }).AsQueryable().OrderBy(e.SortExpression,e.SortDirection);
```

Comment: What is `OrderBy(e.SortExpression,e.SortDirection)`?

Comment: I used that for sorting the output.from the query

Comment: Ok, but how they are defined, and why you use `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Also, there is no such overload that takes something with semantic `Sort Direction` as second parameter.

Comment: I don't know much( I am beginner just started my career).I think this is used when expression tree is constructed. But with out using that AsQuerayable() i got the same error

Comment: OK, but you use `SortExpression` and don't know what is it?

Comment: What I have to do to get o/p.Can you please let me know?

Comment: sort expression is the column name where I clicks on grid view(in browser)

Comment: Ok, generally, you must define `Expression` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please include also the source for the <GridView> control

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing string-based sorting mechanism (GridView.Sorting event) with Linq (lambda expressions based sorting).

This article: [Handle GridView.OnSorting() and create sorting expression dynamically using LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246361/Handle-GridView-OnSorting-using-LINQ) does what you want

Comment: Thank you very much carlos.The link you mentioned is a bit difficult. Can i get some thing simple.

Answer (score 0):

at last I have done the following

```
protected void gridview1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            int p = int.Parse(Session["p"].ToString());
            p++;
            Session["p"] = p;
            if (p % 2 == 0)
            {
                var A = from bk in bookList
                        join ordr in bookOrders
                        on bk.BookID equals ordr.BookID
                        select new
                        {
                            BookID = bk.BookID,
                            BookNm = bk.BookNm,
                            PaymentMode = ordr.PaymentMode
                        };


                gridview1.DataSource = A.OrderBy(x => x.BookID);
                gridview1.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                var A = from bk in bookList
                        join ordr in bookOrders
                        on bk.BookID equals ordr.BookID
                        select new
                        {
                            BookID = bk.BookID,
                            BookNm = bk.BookNm,
                            PaymentMode = ordr.PaymentMode
                        };


                gridview1.DataSource = A.OrderByDescending(x=>x.BookID);
                gridview1.DataBind();

            }



        }
```